# Single jQuery Image Selector for Multiple Fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to figure out the approach to this problem, if someone can't provide a direct solution, I would benefit from a conceptual approach so I can try to solve it myself.

I have a page with text form fields, each field having a corresponding `IconId`. On the page will be list of small image icons (PNG). Goal is when a user clicks on one of the text boxes, it will activate the 100 icons, user can select 1 icon which will add the `IconId` to the corresponding hidden field. When a user clicks on a field that already has a `IconId` assigned or in the hidden field, they can choose a different icon and that swaps out the `IconId`. Page will be submitted as a standard form post via PHP and page framework will be Bootstrap 3 w/ jQuery 1.11.

Here is a Fiddle demonstrating the use case: http://jsfiddle.net/pitashi/xpvt214o/182828/

Comment: Use a data attribute,..  eg.. `data-icon-id="1"` , you can then extract that.

Comment: @Keith ok, but how do I force the images to update the currently selected field if I have multiple fields? If it was just one field and a bunch of images, it's straightforward click image, update text field. But I need to know which field set is being selected so I can update the corresponding IconId field when clicking the desired image.

Comment: Please post the relevant "*[mcve]*" code here in your question, that way the question remains useful in the event that an external site, such as JS Fiddle, falls over, dies, reorganises or deletes content.

Comment: `update the currently selected field if I have multiple fields?`  What you want here is delegated events,.. eg.. If you used a data attribute, you could target all fields with `$(container).on("click", "[data-icon-id]", function () { }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example of using a data attribute,..

I've not actually used icons here, or a hidden field for demo purposes, but it should be easy for you to alter for your needs.

```js
var lastFocus = null;

$(document.body).on("focus", "input", function () {
  lastFocus = this;
});

$(document.body).on("click", "[data-icon-id]", function () {
  $(lastFocus).val(this.dataset.iconId).focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p>Click each LI, and you will get the id inside the last focused input field.</p>
<input /><br>
<input /><br>
<input /><br>


<ul>
  <li data-icon-id="1">Icon 1</li>
  <li data-icon-id="2">Another icon (2)</li>
  <li data-icon-id="3">It's three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is helpful and I am able to make it work; I'm only struggling with the case where i have 3 `inputs` per your example above. I can't use the global selector `$("input")` it needs to be specifically the input that is `active`. Can you please update your snippet to reflect that?

Comment: @JeffSolomon I've updated to cope with multiple inputs, I basically keep a track of the last focused input.

Comment: BAM! yes, perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an unique id to each input field (e.g. iterating them input-1, input-2 etc.). Then, you could store the id of the currently selected input field into a variable of your script. 
When clicking an icon, you select the input field by that saved variable/id and update its corresponding icon-id hidden field.